# "Там царь Кощей над златом чахнет..."

Tags: фольклор, литература

Собственно говоря, откуда эта строчка и кто автор, напоминать не надо.))
Так вот, внезапно подумалось: а почему тут упомянуто, что Кощей - царь? Во всех сказках, если я не ошибаюсь, он "проходит по делу" просто как Кощей Бессмертный (хоть часто его действительно рисуют в короне).
А если он все-таки царь, то какого государства? Чем правит царь Кощей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

О Кощее-Кащее спорили долго, и история его долга, это персонаж и мифов, и народных сказок, а Пушкин вобрал всё и создал своего.

Злодеем и повелителем царства мёртвых его сделала более поздняя традиция. Царство его на Севере. Во времена раннеземледельческих культур наши предки мыслили Север как местонахождение душ своих умерших предков. Море-океан - это Северный Ледовитый океан. Изначальный смысл связан с Космосом. (…Мировое древо, зелёный дуб Лукоморья - оттуда же, из мифов. Полярные сияния - явление непреходящее, а кто им владеет - бессмертный. Полярный Змей и Кощей часто  отождествлялись).

Кошть, кощь в родстве с «кость». Окостенел - умер. Мороз превращал всё в камень. Владения царя Кощея на стеклянных горах в хрустальном дворце - это Север. Фееричесая картина северных сияний, живая мозаика. Сияющие высоты навевали мысли о сказочных богатствах царя царства мёртвых.

Кощей в мифологии во многом схож с божеством Плутоном – Аидом—царем «кощного царства», миром людей, чье существование закончено. «Кощеево зеркало» хранит их память. Еще одна черта, приписываемая Кощею, который «чах над златом». У Кощея в руках ключи от таинственного сундука. Сундук этот представлял собой запечатанный потусторонний мир, и ключи открывали ворота в этот мир. Возможно, сами ворота Ада…

Но, в сущности, Кощей – хранитель не только судеб людей, он необходим для всемирного равновесия смерти и перерождения.

Иногда имя «кощей» связывают со значением «урожай» и «жребий» - «кош». Другая интерпретация имени – слово «кость». Жрецы и жрицы проводили похоронные обряды, собирали обугленные кости, а после предавали их захоронению. Этнографы зафиксировали один обряд, по которому в кощеев день женщины варили и съедали курицу, кости которой собирали и закапывали, чтобы на следующий год выросли из них цыплята. Одно божество христианских мифологий позже стало зваться Кащей-Касьян, он повелевает ветрами.   Празднования прихода весны сопровождались необычными обрядами. В ночь перехода февраля на март ритуал предписывал раздавить в руке сырое куриное яйцо, это символизировало приход конца Кащея, по-другому, конца зимы и холодов. Спутница Кощея - Мара или Морана. В дошедших вариантах сказок она часто уже носит имя Марья, но, несомненно, что это переделка имени могучей и грозной богини зимы и смерти, жены Кощея, дочери Лады, сестры Живы и Лели. Морана у славян в древности считалась воплощением нечистых сил.

Пришло христианство, теперь  бог должен быть один, и он обязательно должен воплощать в себе добро и свет,  Кащей теперь отрицательное божество, злой персонаж в мифических легендах, поверьях, сказках.

Часто Кащей представлен в сказках с короной на голове. Он царствует где-то за тридевять земель в тёмном царстве, у него есть рабы и прислуга, он живет в своем замке.  Он крадет людей, либо ему приносят их в жертву. Никто ничего о нём не знает, его боятся. Так что это отголосок мифов и древних верований.

Comment: а Пушкин вобрал всё

Comment: "Пришло христианство, теперь бог должен быть один". 
Думаю, правильно будет: теперь Бог должен быть един. 

"Одно божество христианских мифологий позже стало зваться Кащей".
Сколько же мифологий, сколько божеств, если Бог един для христиан?

Comment: Интересно, а с чем тогда связан сюжет сказки, что смерть Кощеева находится в игле?

Comment: Тоже много версий.Игла, булавка в народной культуре является предметом-оберегом и одновременно орудием порчи. По восточнославянским представлениям, ведьма, змора или огненный змей  могут оборачиваться иголкой. Следовало ломать и выбрасывать иглу, которой пользовались в ритуальных действиях , а сказки иногда говорят о колдовских способностях Кощея.Другая версия - от представлений о Кащее, кот. возрождается каждый год с морозами:форма иглы - как у соответствующего органа, сломать орган - и больше он не возродится.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что Кощей правит подземным миром и является персонажем хтоническим.

Answer (score 0):

kosten (нем.) - Стоить. Безкоштовно, кошты, - сейчас, по украинским каналам, только и слышно: меньше заплатить, а лучше так задаром. Не наше это слово. Не о прибавочной ли стоимости разговор?

Answer (score 0):

Пушкин знал историю, где царями были правители городов с 5000 жителей и цари земель, по которым бродили охотники и собиратели. К то му же, царь без владения - царь (король Лир).

Answer (score 0):

Пушкин ещё тот "сукин сын", так загадить русский язык  смысловыми вывертами и вместе с тем оставаться признанным знатоком русского языка - это удивительно (мягко говоря)! 
Кощей изначально не герой сказок, а человек, совершающий определённые шаги, использующий определённый способ действия, связанный с освобождением, просветлением. А так как язычники этого не понимали, то исказили толкование слова. 
Да, кощей (пишется со строчной, как и повар, монах, прохожий и т.д.) может быть царём, потому что он занимается просветлением, освобождением, а таких людей всегда ценили на Руси.